# Isolate the name of a repository branch in Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

> **What specific changes need to be made to the `Jenkinsfile` below in order to isolate the name of the branch of the commit into a variable that can be printed out in the logs?**  In the case below, the name of the branch is `GWS-43-getissueforcommit`.

Here are the specifics:

---

**Jenkinsfile:**

---

The following `Jenkinsfile` prints out the branch name in the midst of the output produced by running the `checkout(scm).GIT_ASKPASS` command, but this information is lost when the subsequent line of code ( `sh "echo 'The repo Ask Pass is: ${repoAskPass}'"` ) tries to print out the encapsulated result of the command:

```
node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()
    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            def repoAskPass = checkout(scm).GIT_ASKPASS
            sh "echo 'The repo Ask Pass is: ${repoAskPass}'"
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw err
    }
}
```

---

**Resulting Logs:**

---

The resulting log output is:

```
General SCM<1s
    Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
    Cloning repository http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
     > git init /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket server credentials
     > git fetch --no-tags --progress http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git +refs/heads/GWS-43-getissueforcommit:refs/remotes/origin/GWS-43-getissueforcommit
     > git config remote.origin.url http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git # timeout=10
     > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/GWS-43-getissueforcommit:refs/remotes/origin/GWS-43-getissueforcommit # timeout=10
     > git config remote.origin.url http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git # timeout=10
    Cleaning workspace
     > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
    No valid HEAD. Skipping the resetting
     > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
    Fetching without tags
    Fetching upstream changes from http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket server credentials
     > git fetch --no-tags --progress http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git +refs/heads/GWS-43-getissueforcommit:refs/remotes/origin/GWS-43-getissueforcommit
    Checking out Revision 375b17c4e7453d802d94659836db436553cc7f0c (GWS-43-getissueforcommit)
     > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
     > git checkout -f 375b17c4e7453d802d94659836db436553cc7f0c
     > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
     > git checkout -b GWS-43-getissueforcommit 375b17c4e7453d802d94659836db436553cc7f0c
    Commit message: "isolate ASKPASS"
     > git rev-list --no-walk 268c468a96de0fb27b6f205658a169b38871b581 # timeout=10
    Cleaning workspace
     > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
    Resetting working tree
     > git reset --hard # timeout=10
     > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
    [Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result

echo 'The repo Ask Pass is: null'— Shell Script<1s
    [ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA] Running shell script
    + echo The repo Ask Pass is: null
    The repo Ask Pass is: null
```

---

**Restated Question:**

---

> **How does the above Jenkinsfile need to be modified in order to output the following line in the logs:**

```
The name of the branch containing the commit for this build is: 
GWS-43-getissueforcommit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GIT_ASKPASS` is used for getting user credentials - it is not relevant to the branch.

[Here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Environmentvariables) are the list of variables the plugin sets, which you can use. From here you can see that `GIT_BRANCH` gives you the remote branch and `GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH` gives you the local branch checked out.

```
def branch = checkout(scm).GIT_BRANCH
sh "echo 'The name of the branch containing the commit for this build is: ${branch}'"
```

This prints the remote branch name along with origin prefix (which is usually desirable). But if you want it without the prefix:

```
def branch = checkout(scm).GIT_BRANCH
branch = branch.substring(branch.indexOf('/') + 1)
sh "echo 'The name of the branch containing the commit for this build is: ${branch}'"
```

Comment: I studied your link.  Thank you.  And you solved this OP.  But the git plugin in your link does not seem to provide information about OTHER branches in the linked repository.  Are you willing to comment on [this other, follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50141718/get-information-about-other-branches-from-within-a-jenkinsfile)?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you mentioned `Jenkinsfile` I guess you are using a Multibranch project. If so, the branch name is always available as an environment variable: `env.BRANCH`

Comment: I added the following two lines, and they printed a null value in the logs:  `def envBranch = env.BRANCH` on line one, and then `sh "echo envBranch variable value is: ${envBranch}"`` on line two.  Is this what you meant?