# Get information about other branches from within a Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins Blue Ocean is running on the same local network as a linked Bitbucket Server instance.  A multibranch project in Jenkins is able to create a branch for each branch of a linked Bitbucket repository on the local Bitbucket Server.  But within the Jenkinsfile, I am not able to get information about the other branches.

> **What specific syntax needs to be added to the simplified `Jenkinsfile` below in order for the resulting console log to:**
> 1. Print a complete list of all the branches in the remote repository, and
> 2. Filter the list to include only those branches whose titles contain a specific substring `xyx`?

This question asks about Bitbucket repository branch information within the Bitbucket object model, which should be accessible via the Bitbucket API or CLI.

---

**Jenkinsfile**

---

The simplified code fo the `Jenkinsfile` is as follows.  Note that I have already tried a few approaches:

```
node {
    // Clean workspace before doing anything
    deleteDir()

    try {
        stage ('Clone') {
            def repoUrl = checkout(scm).GIT_URL
            sh "echo 'The repo URL is: ${repoUrl}'"
            def branch = checkout(scm).GIT_BRANCH
            sh "echo 'The name of the branch containing the commit for this build is: ${branch}'"
            sh "git remote show"
            sh "git remote show origin"
        }
    } catch (err) {
        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
        throw err
    }
}
```

The preceding `Jenkinsfile` is not isolating the intended information.

---

**The Logs**

---

The complete logs that result from running the preceding `Jenkinsfile` are as follows:

```
General SCM<1s
    Cloning the remote Git repository
    Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
    Cloning repository http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
     > git init /var/jenkins_home/workspace/ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket server credentials
     > git fetch --no-tags --progress http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git +refs/heads/GWS-43-getissueforcommit:refs/remotes/origin/GWS-43-getissueforcommit
     > git config remote.origin.url http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git # timeout=10
     > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/GWS-43-getissueforcommit:refs/remotes/origin/GWS-43-getissueforcommit # timeout=10
     > git config remote.origin.url http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git # timeout=10
    Cleaning workspace
     > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
    No valid HEAD. Skipping the resetting
     > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
    Fetching without tags
    Fetching upstream changes from http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket server credentials
     > git fetch --no-tags --progress http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git +refs/heads/GWS-43-getissueforcommit:refs/remotes/origin/GWS-43-getissueforcommit
    Checking out Revision 146a9be9f1500df335614cc7d769d14e6de16649 (GWS-43-getissueforcommit)
     > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
     > git checkout -f 146a9be9f1500df335614cc7d769d14e6de16649
     > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
     > git checkout -b GWS-43-getissueforcommit 146a9be9f1500df335614cc7d769d14e6de16649
    Commit message: "remove extraneous info"
     > git rev-list --no-walk ecb67a432da567cf2e6d91f031b8ceb2f59ed087 # timeout=10
    Cleaning workspace
     > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
    Resetting working tree
     > git reset --hard # timeout=10
     > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
    [Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result

echo 'The repo URL is: http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git'— Shell Script<1s
    [ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA] Running shell script
    + echo The repo URL is: http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
    The repo URL is: http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git

General SCM<1s
    > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
     > git config remote.origin.url http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git # timeout=10
    Cleaning workspace
     > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
    Resetting working tree
     > git reset --hard # timeout=10
     > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
    Fetching without tags
    Fetching upstream changes from http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials Bitbucket server credentials
     > git fetch --no-tags --progress http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990/scm/JSP/jenkinsfile-simple-repo.git +refs/heads/GWS-43-getissueforcommit:refs/remotes/origin/GWS-43-getissueforcommit
    Checking out Revision 146a9be9f1500df335614cc7d769d14e6de16649 (GWS-43-getissueforcommit)
     > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
     > git checkout -f 146a9be9f1500df335614cc7d769d14e6de16649
     > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
     > git branch -D GWS-43-getissueforcommit # timeout=10
     > git checkout -b GWS-43-getissueforcommit 146a9be9f1500df335614cc7d769d14e6de16649
    Commit message: "remove extraneous info"
    Cleaning workspace
     > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
    Resetting working tree
     > git reset --hard # timeout=10
     > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
    [Bitbucket] Notifying commit build result

echo 'The name of the branch containing the commit for this build is: GWS-43-getissueforcommit'— Shell Script<1s
    [ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA] Running shell script
    + echo The name of the branch containing the commit for this build is: GWS-43-getissueforcommit
    The name of the branch containing the commit for this build is: GWS-43-getissueforcommit

git remote show— Shell Script<1s
    [ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA] Running shell script
    + git remote show
    origin

git remote show origin— Shell Script<1s
    [ne_GWS-43-getissueforcommit-M2X23QGNMETLDZWFK7IXVZQRCNSWYNTDFJZU54VP7DMIOD6Z4DGA] Running shell script
    + git remote show origin
    fatal: could not read Username for 'http://<bitbucket-ip-on-lan>:7990': No such device or address
    script returned exit code 128
```